# pandoc- tables missing when using environment `tabularx` from package tabularx

Tags: tabularx, pandoc

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}  
\hline  
V & A & R & I \\  
\hline  
1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\  
\hline  
\end{tabularx}  

\end{document}
```

Of course it works well in typesetting. But it does not work when using

```
pandoc xxx.tex -o xxx.pdf
```

or

```
pandoc xxx.tex -o xxx.docx
```

It shows

```
XXXX V & A & R & I  
1 & 2 & 3 &4
```

Can someone help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: More recent versions of pandoc (I tried 2.6) produce tables as expected. Converting to `.docx` is better, but still not there all the way. Besides the fact, that pandoc is the wrong tool to convert from LaTeX to LaTeX, the main issue – `tabularx` not working – is, however, gone.